# How to use selenium to collect information from an element that has not been loaded yet

Tags: java, selenium

hi i am very new to selenium and i want to collect all those elements that have a particular span id.

Problem: When selenium opens the webpage, it shows(by default) only the first three divs containing approx 50 lines of data per div. I want to fetch information(text) from spans contained in all divs. Is there a way to fetch information from those unloaded divs? If not how can i load those divs by controlling the scroll-bar?

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML code along with your question? If possible give us link because other can not imagine about your scenario. If you can not give link then give us some other website link which has similar feature which you want to automate.

Comment: the code is the company copyright so i am not allowed to paste it. But similar feature is followed by facebook which loads subsequent data on scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code for scrolling your page down but fetching information from div without loading will not be possible.

```
WebDriver driver = = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)", "");
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," +
                    "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But as soon as i scroll down to the bottom the upper divs unload. Is there a way that i can know when all the lines in upper three divs have been traversed and can then load next three divs because the page loads only three divs at a time

Comment: As you mentioned in your question that your main task is to fetch all divs data so you can keep the scrolling module code(given by me) in one function and call it from your @test function and whenever new divs get loads then you can collect the text in one array and can try to load new div and then again fetch text from new div. In this way you will be able to collect all divs data.